# Serial correlation for units accidentally picked in pooled-cross section data

Tags: panel-data, autocorrelation, cross-section

I have a pooled cross-section dataset.

Suppose that, for every year from 2010 to 2020, I observe the individuals that apply for a bank loan.

Some individuals apply more than one time, i.e. more than one year (e.g. the first time to buy a house, the second time to buy a PC).

So, sometimes, the same individual appears in more than one cross-section.

I asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/594316/pooled-cross-section-or-very-highly-unbalanced-panel-data) whether that makes my dataset a (very unbalanced) panel dataset.

The answer seems to be no, since the purpose of my study is not to observe individuals over time, and in any case accidentally picking the same individual more than one time is allowed in cross-sectional studies.

Next question is: the reviewer wants to know how we handle autocorrelation, i.e. serial correlation, for the individuals that appear more than one time.

How can I handle it? Can I ignore it or do I have to apply a specific methodology?